# "There are no locations available." when trying to create an Azure Redis Cache

Tags: azure, azure-redis-cache

When I try to create a new Azure Redis Cache and choose a location I just get a "There are no locations available." message.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6r16.png)  Setting everything else first still results in the same error.  Refreshing the page doesn't resolve the issue.  The problem occurs in both IE and Chrome.

[image: error]

Comment: Did you clear cookies and try again. Maybe it helps. Maybe try tomorrow or several hours later. I had just created Redis in West US yesterday and I can see many locations. If nothing helps, you'd better find MS Support I guess.

Comment: Clearing cache/cookies doesn't help.  Contacting MS technical support even for bugs in their website requires a paid support plan.  The problem eventually cleared up on its own, but then came back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with the Azure team via email we were able to narrow down the problem and find a workaround.

There are 3 problems at work here that result in my symptoms:

1. The various New blades in the portal will default you to a disabled subscription.  I believe they currently default to the first subscription (oldest) which may not be an active subscription.  This results in the default behavior upon choosing a blade to be that of no-subscription.
2. The New Redis Cache blade will only show locations if you have selected a valid (not disabled) subscription.  This behavior differs from the other New blades (such as Create VM) which will show you locations even if you have a disabled subscription selected.
3. Changing the resource group will automatically change the subscription and lock it, but changing the subscription in this way will not trigger an update to the blade.  This means that the locations don't get updated for the new subscription because the subscription-changed-event (made up name) was not fired.  In my case, I was always changing the subscription by way of changing the resource group, so I was never able to set the location.

**The workaround:**

Simply change to an active subscription *before* choosing a resource group.  This will cause the locations list to be updated, and you can then choose a resource group after.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this.  It seems to be a bug in the portal.  I can reproduce it if I click "Location" immediately after the "New Redis Cache" blade opens.  However, if I wait a few seconds before clicking "Location", it doesn't repro.

As a workaround, if you close and reopen the "Location" blade it should populate correctly.

We will also work on fixing this in the portal.

Finally, for any issues with Azure Redis Cache you can contact us via email at azurecache@microsoft.com.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I was having generally slow feedback and a number of timeouts on the Azure portal last night, I'm guessing that "wait a few seconds" during such a time might have really been, "wait a few minutes" due to whatever was causing all of the timeouts in the various portal blades.

Comment: Happening again this evening, closing and re-opening the Location blade doesn't seem to help, even after waiting a while (up to several minutes).  Starting the whole process over again (from the +) doesn't seem to help either.  :/

Comment: I left the create dialog up overnight, in the morning I checked the location tab and it still says no locations available.  I would seem that Microsoft doesn't want my money.  :P

Comment: What browser are you using (including version)?  You could try using private mode or a different browser.  We have only been able to reproduce this when clicking "Location" quickly after the create blade opens.

Comment: Another option is to create the cache using Powershell instead of the portal.  The following page has general instructions for using PowerShell in "ResourceManager" mode: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-azure-resource-manager/.  Then use the command "New-AzureRedisCache" to create a new cache.

Comment: For additional support, you can also contact us via email at 'azurecache@microsoft.com'.

Comment: Google Chrome 39.0.217195 m, regular and incognito.  Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17498 Update 11.0.15, inprivate.  I will contact support at that address since at this point it sounds like it is my account that is in a bad state if it is currently working for everyone else.